# Mysql update statement updated Unexpectedly

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

For updating MySql table, i used the query-

```
update TABLE set status=1 and finalStatus_id=1 and id in (1,3,4);
```

I mistakenly wrote **and** in place of **where** and execute the query.

As per query, I was expecting ERROR but it ran successfully. Secondly, I was expected to update status of all rows as 1.
But,
Status of all the rows got updated to 0.(Why this?)

I tried to find out the reason and smililar use of query but cant find.
Why is this? Why it behaved like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is interpreted as:

```
update TABLE
    set status = (1 and (finalStatus_id = 1) and (id in (1, 3, 4));
```

This is a boolean expression.  It will only be "1" (true) when the id is 1, 3, or 4 and the value of `finalStatus_id` is 1.  If all rows are set to `0`, then this is never true.

The query you want is presumably:

```
update TABLE
    set status = 1,
        finalStatus_id = 1 
where id in (1, 3, 4);
```

Commas are used to separate the updates to separate columns, not the boolean `and`.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, the WHERE clause is optional. It's legal syntax to update every row in the table, which you can do by omitting the WHERE clause.

```
UPDATE table SET status=1;
```

Maybe this is not a good language design, to make the *default* be that your update will apply to every row, but this standard SQL syntax, for better or worse.

The MySQL client has a flag `--safe-updates` which prevents you from executing such queries by accident. It treats a query as an error if it's an UPDATE or DELETE and has no WHERE clause. This only works in the MySQL client, not in any programmatic interface. So it doesn't work if you make the same mistake in application code.

The next part is that you set your `status` to an expression. An expression can be a simple value like `1`, but it can also be a more complex expression.

This is a legal expression:

```
1 and finalStatus_id=1 and id in (1,3,4)
```

Since `1` is the same thing as `true`, it's a legal operand for `and`. The other two terms are also boolean conditions.

The result of the whole expressions is a boolean `true` or `false`, which in MySQL is equivalent to `1` or `0`.

So you applied this expression to every row in your table. Certainly it will be `false` on every row where `id` is not in (1,3,4).